Sharing code from nested NextJs route with a shallow path
We have a folder structure that goes like this in NextJS 14:
-app
  -[accountId]
  -layout.tsx
    -[dealId]
    -layout.tsx
      -[propId]
      -layout.tsx
        -page.tsx

We want to our users to be able to share a link w other users and view the UI that is finally rendered within /[propId] (page.tsx).
The problem is that in the parent layouts we are also rendering other components that we want to share (We want to share the final output UI).
We want to share this in
-app
  -[shareId]

Is there a way in NextJS to render the full UI of propId into /[shareId] without having to copy-paste all the code (all layouts.tsx) into the new /share folder?
